# How to use Google News service in my iPhone application

Tags: ios

I am willing to develop an iPhone application that  allows user to be up to date, but I need a source to get information from. I think that Google News is a good fit but I didn't find how I can request it from my application. Are there any web services (like google maps web services) to do that? If not, what is a good choice to help me develop a news application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no developer API for Google News. You can, however, tap into Google News' [various RSS feeds](http://support.google.com/news/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=59255) for a similar experience.